# implementing a function with matrix - differences

Tags: c, matrix, pointer-arithmetic

I have the following function which prints a matrix:

```
void printMat(int* mat, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0 ; i < size ; i++)
        printf("%d ", mat[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Now, suppose I have a certain matrix and I want to implement the print of it by passing it to the function above in three ways:

```
void main()
{
    int mat[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };

    printMat((int*)mat, 6);     //first way//
    printMat((int*)mat+1, 6);   //second way//
    printMat(mat+1, 6);         //third way//
}
```

In the **first** way, the function actually gets the starting address of the matrix. That I understand.

However, I don't understand why in the first way the function actually gets the **address of the second element** in the matrix, and not the **address of the second line** in the matrix (**whereas the latter is being implemented actually by the third way**).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the C operator precedence. A cast is stronger than a `+`

```
(int*)mat + 1 is the same as ((int*)mat) + 1
```

so `mat` is casted to `int*` before adding 1 (hence you increment a "pointer to int")

Here `mat+1` you don't have a cast so it will act like a "row increment" because in this expression `mat` acts as a "pointer to an array of 3 ints".

BTW: Notice that your code have undefined behavior as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The (type) operator is ahead of the binary addition operator (+) in precedence.
If you want the *second way* to be the same as the *third way*, put
`mat + 1` in parenthesis `()` in the second way.

Then,

```
printMat((int*)(mat+1), 6);   //second way//
```

will be same as:

```
printMat(mat+1, 6);         //third way//
```